# API Rest messageContact

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, mobileconnect, sms

I would like to send a triggered SMS using messageContact method without subscribe the contact to the appropriate short or long code and keyword (I know that's a prerequisite for sending SMS in Journey Builder, but i dont want use it!).

I think that I've implemented correctly the call because the response contains the tokenId and not an errore message.

The call is

```json
    {
    "MobileNumbers": [
            "<mobile_number_with_int_call_prefix>"
        ],
        "Subscribe": false,
        "Resubscribe": false,
        "Override": true,
        "messageText": "HELLO WORLD",
        "SendTime": "2012-10-05 20:01"
    }
```

But no messages have been sent... any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to contact them without them opting in?

Comment: Yep, i want to send a transactional SMS

Answer (score 0):

My thought would be to do with the `"MobileNumbers":` - try using camel case

`"mobileNumbers": []`

Comment: I've tried it and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar scenario. Set subscribe and resubscribe to TRUE and add Keyword: [your keyword you already created in mobile connect here]
That way they always get it. Better suggestions also welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same scenario where it seems like the only way, via messageContact, to send to a number that doesn't already exist in MobileConnect is by subscribing them to a keyword. As the messages that I'm sending are intended to be one-time transactional sends I am going the route of setting them as "Subscribers" with a specific identifier as a prefix to the SubscriberKey value. My thinking is that this will allow for easily segmenting and, perhaps, purging of these contacts after they've been sent to.